# ubuntu - ограничение исходящего трафика

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Какие утилиты есть для ubuntu, чтобы ограничить ВЕСЬ исходящий трафик сервера, ну или хотя бы для определенных программ?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/388390/shape-throttle-an-ip-on-the-network-qos

Comment: `wondershaper`?

Answer (score 2):

> хотя бы для определенных программ?

для многих программ может подойти программа *trickle* из [одноимённого пакета](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=trickle&searchon=names&exact=1&suite=all&section=all). (не подойдёт она, как сказано в [`man trickle`](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/trickle/trickle.1.en.html), для статически слинкованных программ и для программ с *setuid*-ом).

в состав пакета входит в том числе и *trickled*, для управления несколькими экземплярами программы *trickle* одновременно.

в "одиночном" варианте (т.е., без взаимодействия с *trickled*) надо запускать *trickle* с опцией `-s`.

ограничивать можно как скорость скачивания - `-d скорость`, так и "отдачи" (*upload*) - `-u скорость`.

---

пример:

```
$ wget https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.0.2o.tar.gz -O /dev/null
...
2018-04-09 17:39:04 (13.4 MB/s) - ‘/dev/null’ saved [5329472/5329472]
```

видим, что скорость скачивания без ограничений: 13.4 MB/s.

```
$ trickle -s -d 100 wget https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.0.2o.tar.gz -O /dev/null
...
2018-04-09 17:41:28 (107 KB/s) - ‘/dev/null’ saved [5329472/5329472]
```

видим, что, указав ограничение на скорость скачивания (`-d кол-во-кб-в-сек`), примерно такую скорость мы и получили: 107 KB/s.